# Woocommerce filter by price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I've been trying to show products in the shop page of my woocommerce store, when I use the normal shortcode method and try to use the filter by price function, it doesn't work at all.However, when I use the function woocommerce_content() to output the products, the filter works without any issues.Is there anyway to make sure the filter works with "echo do_shortcode()" method?
Also, woocommerce_content() method outputs all the products and I couldn't find a way to only output sales or most most purchased products? Is there a way to output a specific type of products while using woocommerce_content() ?

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit=4 columns=4]'); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar();
      // or do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
     ?>
```

Comment: Any specific reason you aren't using the default shop page vs using the shortcode?

Comment: I wanted to design my own custom shop page, if I use page.php then all the changes apply to other pages too.

Comment: Ya, you can still do that without this.  - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: thats what I have tried, all the codes written are in 'woocommerce/archive-product.php' file.